# Building a list in Scala

Tags: scala, list

**Why** is it so hard to build a list in Scala? I know many other languages, and I have never had such a hard time trying to figure out a very simple use case... I spent over an hour on something that should take only 1 minute to implement. I'm a bit upset at this point which is why I'm asking for help now

**Problem:**
What I'm trying to do is pass in an array of integers and return an array of the cubes of the odd numbers.

**Constraints:** I have to use Lists, I have to use a for loop

This is what I have so far:

```
    def cubes(a1: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
        var a2 = List[Int]()

        for(i <- 0 to a1.size-1){
            if(a1(i)%2 != 0) a2 :+ a1(i) * a1(i) * a1(i)
        }

        //If I try to print out the first element I get an error
        println(a2(0))
    }

    cubes(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
```

This is the error

```
list1.scala:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: List[Int]
        println(a2(0))
               ^
```

**Question:** How can I refactor my code so that I can build a List given my constraints

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `var` you can take advantage of that a list can be returned from a for-comprehension using the `yield` keyword.

Example that assigns the result to a list variable and returns it:

```
def cubes(a: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  val cubesList = for (item <- a if item % 2 != 0) yield {
    Math.pow(item, 3).toInt
  }
  cubesList  //return the list created by the loop
}
```

Testing it:

```
scala> cubes(List(1,2,3,4,5)) foreach println
1
27
125
```

The above code can be shortened by returning the result of the for-comprehension directly. Then you can also omit the curly braces:

```
def cubes(a: List[Int]): List[Int] = 
  for (item <- a if item % 2 != 0) 
  yield Math.pow(item, 3).toInt
```

Comment: This works but how can I add elements to a list and then return it? Also I'm having a hard time even printing an element in a list. Doing a2(0) keeps throwing an error, I have no idea why

Comment: I may have figured it out. Ill post an answer

Comment: @Phillip You do not actually have to create a list yourself. The `for` will return a list to you. You can actually do `val list = for ....` to get the list. Also, you should probably not use `return`, see [here](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html), just let the return value be on the last line in your method. Edited my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: I understand that the for will return a list. My question was in regards to specifically building a list. But your solution does work, I will use that if it wasn't part of my constraint to build a list

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a `ListBuffer` and convert it to a list before returning. Lists are immutable so we have to use a list buffer.

Also the error I was getting was because the return type is `List[Int]` but I wasn't returning anything and I was trying to print which I'm guessing returns some type of `Unit`

I'm still very upset it took this long to figure out... Oh well

Here's the solution:

```
   import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

    def cubes(a1: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
        var cubes = new ListBuffer[Int]()

        for (item <- a1 if item % 2 != 0) yield {
            cubes += Math.pow(item, 3).toInt
        }

        val cubesList = cubes.toList

        return cubesList
    }

    println(cubes(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)))
    println(cubes(List(3, 5, 6, 7, 11)))
```

Comment: 1 - A `ListBuffer` is already mutable so `cubes` does not need to be a `var`. 2 - There is no reason to create `cubesList`. Just return `cubes.toList`. 3 - Idiomatic Scala does not use the `return` statement. 4 - Your constraints, as posted, don't actually state that you have to build a `List` from scratch. (Which is also **not** idiomatic Scala.) @Shaido has the better solution.